# Screen Flickering Pink - Windows

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I have been having screen flickering issue for a while. I imagined it was hardware issue as my Dell Inspiron 7567 gaming laptop is now very old. But strangely I found recently that when using the Movies and TV app, the flicker vanishes as fast as the seek bar and the buttons goes away. Its like this app alone doesn't get the flickers.

I thought it might be because of graphics card and that this app might be using the non-faulty graphics card. To check which graphics card might be causing issue, I tried disabling the graphics card one after the other. But that didn't make much a difference either. If you want to know, I have NVIDIA and Intel graphics cards.

Can anyone help me out with this issue. Now that I think this might not entirely hardware issue I was hoping to fix it with your help. Attaching a picture of my screen for your reference.
[screen_flicker_pink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh1z4.jpg)

Comment: The quick way to test whether it's software or hardware is take a screenshot rather than a photo, then look at it on another computer.

Comment: Also, if you think NOT hardware, then update Video, Chipset and BIOS as well.

Comment: Could it be the display refresh rate causing the issue? When playing a movie, the refresh rate might slow to 24, 30 or 60 frames/sec. Try reducing the rate to see if flicker stops.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Since you've left out the OS, here are instructions for Windows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-display-refresh-rate-in-windows-c8ea729e-0678-015c-c415-f806f04aae5a

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that this happens when one pin on the monitor cable or cord bad and with notebooks the ribbon cable in display panel. A quick test would plug a monitor in display port. If the issue is not there you found it. If not I am not sure.

I hope this is helpful.